# How do I get a Canon LBP 2900 B Printer working?

Tags: 11.10, printing

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 , I have a Canon LBP 2900 B model printer. 
I installed two .deb driver packeges (cndrvcups-capt,cndrvcups-common) with gs-esp dependency package, then configured the printer, using informations given in the Ubuntu community and from many other sources from the Internet.

I am sure that all configurations are right according rules (ccp:/var/ccpd/fifo0) but when I give a print -nothing happens (not printing).

I saw another matter - a new printer automatically configured (LBP2900-2) in device uri usb://Canon/LBP2900

Using Ubuntu 11.04, I installed the printer with the same method cited above, then I printed a test page and many other pages successfully, but after restarting the PC, trying to print - nothing happens.

I saw that a second printer configured in the address

> usb://Canon/LBP2900
>   I connect Canon LBP2900 with Computer using USB port